# Parsing ambiguous input with Antlr

Tags: antlr, antlr3, ambiguity

I have been trying for a few days to parse some text that consists of text and numbers (I've called it a sentence in my grammar).

```
    sentence options {
          greedy=false;
     } 
         : (ANY_WORD | INT)+;
```

I have a rule that needs to parse a sentence that finishes with an INT

```
    sentence_with_int 
        : sentence INT;
```

So if I had some input that was " the  number of size 14 shoes bought was 3 " then sentence_with_int would be matched not just sentence. I'm sure there is a better way to do this but I'm just learning the tool.

Thanks, Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grammar:

---

```
grammar Test;

sentence_with_int 
  :  sentence {System.out.println("Parsed: sentence='"+$sentence.text+"'");}
     INT      {System.out.println("Parsed: int='"+$INT.text+"'");}
  ;

sentence
  : (ANY_WORD | INT)+
  ;

ANY_WORD
  :  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+
  ;

INT
  :  ('0'..'9')+
  ;

WS  
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {$channel=HIDDEN;}
  ;
```

---

does exactly that. Here's a little test harness:

```
import org.antlr.runtime.*;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream("the number of size 14 shoes bought was 3");
        TestLexer lexer = new TestLexer(in);
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        TestParser parser = new TestParser(tokens);
        parser.sentence_with_int();
    }
}
```

First generate a parser & lexer (assuming all your files, and the ANTLR jar, are in the same directory):

```
java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool Test.g
```

and compile all `.java` source files:

```
javac -cp antlr-3.2.jar *.java
```

and finally run the `Demo` class:

```
java -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar Demo
```

(*on Windows, replace the `:` with a `;`*)

which produces the following output:

```
Parsed: sentence='the number of size 14 shoes bought was'
Parsed: int='3'
```

Comment: No problem @Richard, although I didn't do much: your grammar was fine to begin with! :)